# lsblk does not return the entire line for the results

Tags: util-linux

I am having trouble with the command below:

```
ssh -q  -o PubkeyAuthentication=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=2 -o BatchMode=yes SERVERNAME "lsblk -il" 2>/dev/nul
```

It returns the results I am looking for until the result is longer than 80 characters in one row then it cuts it off.

I would like the full results of the command if possible.

I am running SuSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3.

Comment: Works for me. What distribution is the server running, what version?

Comment: Linux Enterprise Server 11.3.3, I was able to bypass the issue by using this "lsblk -i -o NAME,MOUNTPOINT" I would still like to know why that happened. @Giles

Comment: 1. If you run `lsblk -il` on the remote server do you get the results you expect? 2. If you omit the `2>/dev/null` is there any relevant error message? 3. When you write that "it cuts it off", do you mean that the characters 81 _et seq_ on that line are truncated, or that no further lines of output are produced? 4. What happens if you pipe the output into, say, `less` - does it work as expected again?

Comment: Is that SuSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3? What is the version of the `util-linux` package?

Answer (score 4):

Versions of util-linux before [this commit](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/commit/lib/tt.c?h=stable/v2.24&id=3785056ca8115d4c0b402abf788219be6203ebb3), first included in version 2.23, truncate the output to the terminal width even if the output is not a terminal. Given [how the terminal width is determined](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/include/ttyutils.h?h=stable/v2.22#n82), you need to redirect standard input to `/dev/null` to ensure that the utility believes that there's no terminal, and set the environment variable `COLUMNS` to a large value to fake a wide terminal (there's no way to say “unlimited”).

```
ssh … SERVERNAME 'COLUMNS=999 lsblk -il </dev/null'
```

Versions since 2.23 are fine.